# How can I loop over a multidimensional array and save the result in an array?

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I want to fill in an empty 4D array. I have created a pre-allocated array (data_4d_smoothed) with 80 x 80 x 44 x 50. I want to loop through all (50) volumes of the data (data_4d), smooth them separately and store the results in data_4d_smoothed. Basically:

```
data_4d_smoothed = np.zeros(data_4d.shape)

sigma = 0.7
for i in data_4d[:, :, :, i]:
    smoothed_vol = gaussian_filter(i, sigma=sigma)
    data_4d_smoothed.append(smoothed_vol)
```

The gaussian_filter should take every volume (the last dimension of the 4d array), do the operation, and save it into data_4d_smoothed. But obviously, this is not a 2D array and I think I need a nested loop to fill this empty list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work without looping:

```
from scipy.ndimage import gaussian_filter
data_4d = np.random.rand(80,80,44,50)
data_4d_smoothed = gaussian_filter(data_4d, sigma = (sigma, sigma, sigma, 0))
```

Basically make the last dimension's `sigma = 0`, so that it doesn't do the convolution in that dimension.

Checking:

```
data_4d_0 = gaussian_filter(data_4d[..., 0], sigma = sigma)  #filter first image

np.allclose(data_4d_0, data_4d_smoothed[..., 0])             #first image from global filter

True
```

Comment: This gives me False. Sigma is a property of the function - irrespective of the dimentions (gaussian_filter). So I don't think this fits :( the function should take 50 volumes one-by-one - the last dimension - apply the function property, and then save it in the output again as a 4D array.

Comment: You're not using `scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter`?  Then what are you using?

Comment: SORRY IT WORKED! can you explain what happens here?

Comment: A convolution with a `sigma = 0` gaussian kernel just returns the original array, so by using `0` as the `sigma` in the 4th dimension, you only convolve over the first three dimensions.